# Change Colour of Group Box Group Title Name

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows, groupbox

How I can change the `GroupBox` title colour?

The default colour is blue and I would like to alter that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using something like the following:

```
groupBox1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
```

It should change to the desired color.

Answer (score 1):

In WinForms - change the **ForeColor** property of the Group Box to the desired color.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the `ForeColor` property?